# I have these problems with 'Connection' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ADODB' and 'Recordset' is ambiguous with 'ADODB'

Tags: vb.net, migration, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

I already checked that I only had one ADODB reference. I tried the clean solution but nothing change. I migrated this project from VS2010 to VS2017.

here's my code:

```
  Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

  Module globalmodule

   Public conn As New ADODB.Connection
   Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Public rss As New ADODB.Recordset
   Public trs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Public sql As String

Public Function Opendb()
    If conn.State = 1 Then conn.Close()
    conn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbEmployee;Data Source=TECHNOPU\SQL;")
    Return 0
End Function
Function EmailAddressCheck(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean

    Dim pattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$"
    Dim emailAddressMatch As Match = Regex.Match(emailAddress, pattern)
    If emailAddressMatch.Success Then
        EmailAddressCheck = True
    Else
        EmailAddressCheck = False
    End If
    If EmailAddressCheck = False Then
        MsgBox("Entervalid E-mail ID")
    End If

End Function


Public empid As String


 End Module
```

Comment: You should really be using SqlClient rather than ADODB via COM to talk to SQL Server.

Comment: Also email addresses can start with a number and be a single character before the @.

Comment: how to do it exactly?

Comment: You may use `Return True` statement on `emailAddressMatch.Success`, because it is look like ambiguous if you are assigning a Boolean to a Function... and, in the `Else` statement in the `emailAddresMatch.Success`'s If statement, you may simplify it to: `MsgBox("Entervalid E-mail ID")` and on the next line type `Return False` on your code, so, you don't need to use 2 if statements when the statement has a same "Condition" that has to be evaluated.

Comment: thank you guys for responding. I just started making love with programming. really needs guidance from expert.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but just in case this helps someone else.  I had the same problem today, and like the OP the first thing I did was to check that I didn't have conflicting versions of ADODB referenced.

Everything looked good, so I was stumped for a while.  I tried cleaning the solution, exiting and re-loading Visual Studio, checked the references again to no avail.

Turns out that although Visual Studio reports that only one version of ADODB was referenced in the project file I had the following;

```
<ItemGroup>
<COMReference Include="ADODB">
  <Guid>{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>8</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>primary</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
<COMReference Include="ADODB">
  <Guid>{B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>6</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>1</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```

Removing the offending COMReference (version 2.8 in my case) from the project file and reloading the project did the job!